# Python code to read in .txt and create a .csv table by bytes

Tags: python, byte

I have a very large .txt file with 59 columns of data. Each column is specific byte size. Is there a way to read in the .txt file and assign it or convert it to a .csv table by column byte sizes?

I haven't tried the code yet, as I'm locked up on the column sizes varying by specific byte sizes (ie. col1 = 6 bytes, col2 = 2 bytes, col3 = 13 bytes...etc.).

Do I need to create the table in python first?

Comment: if columns have fixed sizes then you could try [pandas.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) (`fwf` means `fixed-width fields`) and later you can save `pandas.to_csv()`

Comment: you can also read it using standard `read()` and create list `[line[:6], line[6:6+2], line[6+2:6+2+13], ...]` and later save this list/row in `.csv` file using standard module `csv`. If you run it in loop then you don't have to create full table but only list with elements in one row.

Comment: Thank you furas, I will research this option after I've tried Jeremy's

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.read(num_bytes)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) on a file pointer. Use this to read in each column and create a dictionary that you can write to a csv file, or just [write as you parse it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). However, if you run into an exception while reading/writing, it will be more difficult to find the issue and you could end up with an incomplete csv file.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I'll research the .read(num_bytes) option. Will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: @strueb don't forget that you have to also read `new line` at the end of every line - and `new line` may use 1 or 2 bytes depends on system (Linux may use 1 byte, Windows may use 2 bytes)